# How to use chisquare test to compare the statistical significance of the difference of frequencies of the categories of a categorical variable?

Tags: r, datatable, frequency, chi-squared

let's say that I have a table as follows

```
            SSE1  SSE2  SSE3  SSE4  SSE5
frequncy     125   200   259   300   200
```

And I wish to use `chisq.test` to see if these values are statistically different from each other or not. But I don't know how yo properly apply it. Thanks.

Comment: are you having trouble with the coding or picking the proper test? if it is picking a proper test this question might be better suited for a stat exchange

Comment: I am having a trouble with the coding because I don't know what is the null hypothesis. Would apprrciate if you can show me how.

Comment: The question is a little too vague to help. Can you add more context to the problem? We can't decide your null hypothesis

Comment: The null hypithesis is : there is no significant difference between these values. The alternative hypothesis is : there is a significant difference between these values

Comment: try `chisq.test(c(125,200,259,300,200))`